# Make keystate fire only fire once

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm coding a menu and use `keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_KEY]` to detect when a key is pressed in a cycle like this:

```
if (Button1 && keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
{
    Button1 = false;
    Button2 = true;
}
else if (Button2 && keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
{
    Button2 = false;
    Button3 = true;
}
else if (button3 && keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
{
    //and so on
}
```

The problem with this setup however is that when the user presses the down key the keystate fires multiple times keeping the conditions for button 2 to switch to button 3 active and so on. So how do I make the keystate fire only once, or at least fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: I believe this is related to firmware and you are receiving keys from a keypad. right?

Comment: @Sean83 yes, I'm receiving keys from the keypad.

Comment: @StackOverflow unclear what you want to achieve. If you want user to release button before reacting to it again, you probably want to use keydown/keyup events inastead of keystate (be aware that key event is repeated, but it have a bool flag to figure out if it is real one or repeated).

Comment: @keltar thanks, that was the exact solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your system (CPU) runs too fast. To avoid it, You can use either timer or delay.

To simply solve, you can use delay. At the end, Try

```
delay(1000); // which means delay 1000 clock cycles.
```

You can adjust the length by modifying the number (i.e. 1000) but please be aware of that using delay function could be critical in a complex system. In that system, Timer could be used but more complicated to implement than this.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, although with this method there is noticeable input lag. Thanks though.

Comment: Added some comments. As I do not know what system you are working on exactly, so I cannot give you a direct answer for timer.